# Failing to download a zipped csv file using python requests library

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, zip

Am trying to download a zipped csv file from https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm.

To see the file select Report: Bhavcopy & and Date:18-06-2021. It gives zip file fo18JUN2021bhav.csv.zip with url https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2021/JUN/fo18JUN2021bhav.csv.zip

Now when I use requests library to make a get call to the zipped csv url (with appropriate headers), I get [404] error.

Is there a way to download it programatically ? Thank you !

Comment: Could be post this headers as well? Because I get https status 403

Comment: 404 indicates the resource is not found. recheck your url and headers

Answer (score 1):

To get the file, set `User-Agent` and `Referer` HTTP headers:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# change filetype and date you want to search for:
url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch?h_filetype=fobhav&date=18-06-2021&section=FO"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
    "Referer": "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
csv_url = "https://www1.nseindia.com" + soup.a["href"]

print("Downloading {}...".format(csv_url))
with open(csv_url.split("/")[-1], "wb") as f_out:
    f_out.write(requests.get(csv_url, headers=headers).content)
print("Done.")
```

Downloads `fo18JUN2021bhav.csv.zip` file:

```
Downloading https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2021/JUN/fo18JUN2021bhav.csv.zip...
Done.
```

```sh
$ ls -alF fo18JUN2021bhav.csv.zip 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 632963 june 20 23:11 fo18JUN2021bhav.csv.zip
```

Comment: Hello, would you be able to tell how to access https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY 500 ? I tried using the same headers which you gave, but giving 401 repeatedly.